# wkhtmltopdf in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am new to Oracle Apex CRM. I have application where i need reports to be exported to pdf. I have worked in .net application and there I have used wkhtmltopdf for exporting html to pdf.

But I am not sure if I can use wkhtmltopdf in Oracle Apex ?

Can anyone help me whether wkhtmltopdf is supported in Oracle Apex ? any reference

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Oracle Apex Interactive Report, the export as PDF feature is already available. You can use the search bar to download the report as PDF. This can be configured on the Report Attributes tab in an Interactive Reporting component.  [Apex Interactive Report Action Options]

[Oracle Apex Interactive Report Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/175zC.png)

You can even create a link to directily download the report using the "PDF" request option as follow:

your application url: http://example.com/apex/f?p=MYAPPID:MYPAGE:PDF
lets say Interative Report is on page 6 of application id 100: http://example.com/apex/f?p=100:6:PDF

Answer (score 0):

If the wkhtmltopdf executable is visible to the server, you can create a job with [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72300).

Comment: but my question is .. can I use wkhtmltopdf in Oracle Apex? because I can't find any code reference /link where wkhtmltopdf is used in Oracle Apex

Comment: @Mahajan344 You cannot directly call the application from Oracle Apex afaik, but you can call PL/SQL Stored Procedures in Oracle APEX, which will allow you to use DBMS_SCHEDULER.

Answer (score 0):

You must use to PL/SQL and then you can call this in your Page. But There is already a pdf download in Apex function.

https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r50/PDF%20Printing/Creating%20PDF%20Reports%20with%20Oracle%20Application%20Express%205.0%20and%20Oracle%20REST%20Data%20Services.html

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before answering any question. Thanks.